# Identificar Dispositivos en Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Como puedo saber q dispositivo se conecto a mi applicacion angular? me gustaria identificarlo para poder hacer q solo dispositivos ios se puedan conectar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás haciendo tu aplicación en Angular5 te recomiendo este plugin:
https://github.com/KoderLabs/ngx-device-detector

Demo: https://koderlabs.github.io/ngx-device-detector/

La otra opción es utilizar simple javascript.

Utilizando `navigator.userAgent` puedes obtener el dispositivo, navegador y demás información:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  console.log(ua);
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Mobile|mobile|CriOS/i.test(ua))
    {
       console.log('iOs');
    }
    else if(/Chrome/i.test(ua))
    {
       console.log('Chrome');
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('Desktop');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```